# How to install librabbitmq-dev in alpine environment?

Tags: php-extension

How to install librabbitmq-dev in alpine environment? I want to install rabbitmq,but install dependent first ,how to install librabbitmq-dev in alpine environment.Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can install [rabbitmq client](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/rabbitmq-c-dev) with:

```
apk add rabbitmq-c-dev
```

Then if you need it in php, you can run:

```
pecl install amqp-1.10.0
```

You can set [whatever version](https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp)

Don't forget to enable the extension aswell

Comment: Thanks for this! 
It may be helpful to update the answer with the command to enable the extension as well:
(`docker-php-ext-enable amqp`)